# knockout computed array not updating when function updates observable array used in computed

Tags: knockout.js

I have the following computed observable witch basically divides the `modelViewModels` observableArray into another array to repsresent rows (logic isn't the issue though)

this is being defined in the constructor

```
self.selectModelRows = ko.computed(function () {
    alert("computing");
    var result = [],
        row,
        colLength = parseInt(self.selectModelRowCount(), 10);

    for (var i = 0, j = self.modelViewModels.length; i < j; i++) {
        if (i % colLength === 0) {
            if (row) {
                result.push(row);
            }
            row = [];
        }
        row.push(self.modelViewModels()[i]);
    }

    if (row) {
        result.push(row);
    }
    return result
});
```

i put the alert there for debugging.
the alert happens the first time when the constructor is run
but i have the following function which updates the `modelViewModels` that is used in the computed

```
self.getModels = function () {
    alert("getting");
    var self = this;
    self.modelViewModels([]);

    $.when(self.dataContext.getAvailableModels(self.selectedSeriesOption()))
        .done(function (data) {
            ko.utils.arrayForEach(data.Models, function (item) {
                var modelViewModel = new ModelViewModel();
                modelViewModel.Model = item.ModelNumber;
                   //more logic will be added
                self.modelViewModels.push(modelViewModel);
            });
        })
        .fail(function (message) {
            alert("failed");
        });
}
```

when the function is called i see the `"getting"` alert but the computed function is not called again, the `"computing"` alert never happens and there are no errors in console.

not sure what else i need to be doing to get the computed to update after the `getModels` function is called.

Comment: can you please make jsfiddle example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside your computed function the `for` loop will not get called because you are getting array length in wrong way.

`self.modelViewModels.length` will always be evaluated to `0`. So, the nothing inside the `for` will be executed and hence you are not reading any `observable` object, which result in ***no-dependency*** and no calling for that computed function.

Change your code to be `self.modelViewModels().length`. just add **()**

Comment: Thank you the () on the end of observables continues to get me!